# How to paginate ajax loaded data?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pagination

I load data from form using JQuery post.

```
$("#SortItmesForm").submit(function() {
    $.post("filtItems.php",
        $("#FiltItemsForm").serialize(),
        function(data) {
            /*alert(data);*/
            $('#results').html(data);
        }
    );
    return false; //Code after form submitted
});
```

FiltItems.php output to

```
<div id="results"></div>
```

is as follows.

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Could anybody give me some guidance, how to paginate loaded results. Preferably with JQuery.

I've tried many JQuery plugins, but none of them didn't seem to work with ajax loaded data.

Comment: What do you mean 'Pageinate'. What you have seems to work fine by itself

Comment: Hi John. List is longer than in the example (may reach 1000 items). What I would like to do is to paginate loaded list let's say 20 items per page and then browse results without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naturally, your css will also be important in this case. Let's suppose you wanted each li to show as a page.

```
<ul id="list_container">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
<a href="javascript:paginate.move('left');">&lt;</a> | <a href="javascript:paginate.move('right');">&gt;</a>
```

css:

```
#results{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#list_container{
    width:600px;
    margin-left:0px;
}

#list_container li{
    width:200px;
    float:left;
}
```

js:

```
var paginate = {
    cur_offset: 0,
    move: function move(dir)
    {
        if(dir == 'left')
        {
            paginate.cur_offset -= 200;
            $('#list_container').animate({marginLeft: paginate.cur_offset + 'px'}, 1000);
        }
        else
        {
            paginate.cur_offset += 200;
            $('#list_container').animate({marginLeft: paginate.cur_offset + 'px'}, 1000);
        }
    }
};
```

Obviously you would want to make provisions so if you're on page 1 you disable the left arrow and last page you disable right but those are easy to handle.

There's also a chance I misunderstood your question. If you're having a problem getting the browser to render the results of your ajax call, then it is likely you need to set the dom elements like so:

```
var elem = $('<div>');
elem.attr('id', some_id);
elem.html(data.html); // assuming you pass json, if not then just data
$('#results').append(elem);
```

And also, look into jquery .live if certain functions aren't working with your newly created dom elements.

As for plugins - that's pretty vague. I don't know of a "pagination" plugin for jquery off the top of my head since pagination is a pretty simple thing to do. I've never found the need to search for a basic plugin.

If this answer is sort of useful but needs more info, let me know and I will update if possible.

Comment: Thank you for reply Kai Qing!! Reason I was looking for plugin is because I'm not very familiar with JavaScript and JQuery. I will try to implement what you have suggested. Your answer is very useful, thanks again!